# self parameter and metaprogramming

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Well, code speaks more (I have hard-coded some things, to isolate the problem and make the question shorter):

```
class wrapper:
    def __init__( self, func ):
        self.func = func
    def __call__( self, *args ):
        print( "okay, arg = ", args[0] )
        self.func( self, args )

class M( type ):
    def __new__( klass, name, bases, _dict ):
        _dict[ "f" ] = wrapper( _dict[ "f" ] ) 
        return type.__new__( klass, name, bases, _dict )

class AM( metaclass = M ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.a = 0 
    def f( self, a ):
        self.a = a 

am = AM()
print( am.a ) # prints 0, expected
am.f( 1 )  # prints: "okay, arg = 1"
print( am.a ) # prints 0 again, also expected
```

I want the second print to show `1`, instead of `0`. In other words, is it possible, and if so - how, to pass the "real self" to my wrapper?

Note: I **know** why this prints `0` and I **know** what is the problem here ( `wrapper`'s self is passed, instead of the object, that calls `f`), but I don't know how to solve it.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT** - thanks all for the answers, +1 from me. But I think I need to do this with class, as I need to store some additional info (like metadata) (this is simplified version of my real problem). Is it possible and how, if so? Sorry for not specifying this at the very beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `wrapper` a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) so that you know the specific instance being poked.

Comment: Could you give me some examples? I didn't get it, I am missing something..(there's nothing similar like this in C++, right?)

Comment: A descriptor is simply a class that Python passes extra information about the class and instance it's bound to when calling the descriptor's `__get__()` or `__set__()` methods.

Comment: Hm, I see. I think that this is going to work for me. But then, how to call the function with arguments. `__get__` takes 3 args -  `self, obj, objtype`. In `__init__` I can store the function as member, but what about arguments? Also, in `__get__` I cannot return `self.func( obj )` ? (`self.func` is the stored cunstion and `obj` is the calling object; when I return `self.func`, this really returns function, but if return `self.func( obj )` `None` :? I need this, as it seems, that the first parameter( self ) should be explicitly passed? Otherwise, I get error for less parameters ) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Return a function that sets the attribute on the class appropriately.

Comment: I edited my comment before seeing you answer. Anyway, I get your point, I'll try.

Answer (score 6):

Use function wrapper, instead of class one. Closure will take care of the rest:

```
>>> def wrapper(meth):
...     def _wrapped_meth(self, *args):
...             print('okay, arg = ', args)
...             meth(self, *args)
...     return _wrapped_meth
...
>>> class M(type):
...     def __new__(klass, name, bases, dct):
...             dct['f'] = wrapper(dct['f'])
...             return type.__new__(klass, name, bases, dct)
...
>>> class AM(metaclass=M):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.a = 0
...     def f(self, a):
...             self.a = a
...
>>> am = AM()
>>> print(am.a)
0
>>> am.f(1)
okay, arg = (1,)
>>> print(am.a)
1
>>>
```

Comment: The closure isn't the only ingredient. You only get `self` becaues the class recognized `wrapper` as a method and generates an instance method descriptor for it.

Comment: Nice! +1 for now. could you, please, explain how this works. I mean - the wrapper..I have seen such wrappers, but they all return the help function, in this case - `_wrapped_meth`. Here, the function returns its argument - `meth`. When and how `_wrapped_meth` is called/used.

Comment: @delnan - really? I can do this with class? How? Because I need to store some additional information - some other members (metadata), etc. inside the wrapper.

Comment: @Kiril: Of course you can, if you don't mind getting into descriptors - see other answers. Note however that you can also have extra state with closures (just add local variables to `wrapper` and use them in `_wrapped_meth`) - it only gets impractical when you need additional methods.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov - Oops, `return meth` should be `return _wrapped_meth`

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers or at least - give some extra points here (: Using descriptors was the solution for my problem, but I use your answer, too - I still need similar function wrapper. Anyway, thanks a lot! (:

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `wrapper` class a non-data descriptor, as described in the [Functions and Methods](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm#functions-and-methods) section of Raymond Hettinger's excellent [*How-To Guide for Descriptors*](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) -- which in this case is pretty easy since it just means giving the class a `__get__()` method which creates and returns the wrapped method desired.

Here's what I mean:

```
class wrapper:
    def __init__( self, func ):
        self.func = func

    def __get__( self, instance, owner ):
        def wrapped( *args ):
            print( "okay, arg = ", args[0] )
            return self.func( instance, *args )
        return wrapped
```

Using a class means you can easily add other members and/or metadata as necessary.

Comment: +1 - That is **exactly** what I did, combining the other two answers (=